# Hide view on scroll in NestedScrollView and take it's place

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, material-design

I would like the yellow LinearLayout to hide as I'm scrolling the NestScrollView. Preferably with the parallax effect. What I was able to achieve already was increase alpha and set visibility to gone on appBar scroll. But I want the recyclerView below it to take it's space as I'm scrolling. Thanks

[image: my layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I got it to work perfectly.

**1. Be above RecyclerView**

Added as a row with different layout, used getItemViewType() to specify different view for that first row.

**2. Disappear on RecyclerView scroll with parallax effect**

Had to override AppBar's addOnOffsetChangedListener() which provided me with verticallOffset variable which I used to translate just the first row in recyclerView

```
recyclerView.getChildAt(0).setTranslationY(verticallOffset / 2);
```

**3. RecyclerView take its place when it dissapears**

Still using the verticallOffset:

```
 if (alpha < -200) {
            readingsRecyclerAdapter.hideFirstRow();
        }
```

and then inside the readingsRecyclerAdapter I removed the row

```
public void hideFirstRow() {
        if (headerShowing) {
            appsList.remove(0);
            notifyItemRemoved(0);
            headerShowing = false;
        }
    }
```

notifyItemRemoved(0); is important here as it causes the recyclerview to take the first rows empty space.